# AnonymousAuthenticationFilter intercepts request after successful login with Custom Authentication Provider

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

We have a **CustomAuthenticationProvider**(AuthenticationProvider) developed for Spring which works with **CustomAuthenticationRequest**(Authentication), **CustomAuthentication**(Authentication), a **CustomUser**.

Once we validate credentials when our Controller is invoked we create a CustomAuthenticationRequest based on the credentials.

```
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
securityContext.setAuthentication(new CustomAuthenticationRequest(new CustomUser(account.getUsername())));
```

Debug login confirms that the **CustomAuthenticationRequest** has been stored in the HTTPSession.

```
HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@730db7d8: Authentication: pro.someplace.spring.CustomAuthenticationRequest@730db7d8' stored to HttpSession: 'org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@5da80010
```

The WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter registers our AuthenticationProvider:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder)
             throws Exception {
    builder.authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider());
}
```

And establishes what can and cannot be seen by anonymous and authenticated users.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login", "/registration").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
}
```

The problem we have is that before the **FilterSecurityInterceptor** can consult which AuthenticationProvider is appropriate the AnonymousAuthenticationFilter steps in:

```
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@4cc1f847: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd148a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 74DB809F1CB5CFB1F977EC20B37B218E; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
```

If I remove the AnonymousAuthenticationFilter then I cannot access permitAll() in the configuration (different error).

Curiously, I notice this logging message at the end of request processing:

```
SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Ok. So the **SecurityContextPersistenceFilter** should have persisted the context in the HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.

But when the next request appears the **SecurityContextPersistenceFilter** has no such object. Was it saved at all? Was it removed?

```
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /ordervalidator at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
```

How can I configure spring to allow authenticated users where I want them and use my **CustomAuthenticationProvider** when available in the HTTPSession? Where is the security object and why is it not being stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And so will be as dumb as it sounds. The front end is React and so we were returning a cookie to the front end however the front end was not being returned to us. As soon as I manually insert cookies into requests I have trapped in either (Postman or Burp) my Context can be found.

This is a cautionary tale as there is a generational difference between the frontend React and the backend (Spring) developers. The backend expect cookies and this is assumed, the front end *"...have no idea why we would want them and its a bad idea"*.